# Countable unions and sigma-algebras

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let C be a countable partition of E, and let G be the collection of all sets that are countable unions of elements taken from C. Show that G is a sigma-algebra.

Can someone explain this step by step, because I'm really lost here :/

Comment: Closing this?! Closing clear questions from people that are "really lost" is *bad*.

Answer (score 2):

You must show three things:

1. $E\in\mathscr{G}$;
2. if $\mathscr{A}\subseteq\mathscr{G}$ is countable, then $\bigcup\mathscr{A}\in\mathscr{G}$; and
3. if $A\in\mathscr{G}$, then $E\setminus A\in\mathscr{G}$.

Let’s take them in order.

1. $\mathscr{C}$ is a partition of $E$, so by the definition of *partition* we know that $\bigcup\mathscr{C}=E$. Is $\bigcup\mathscr{C}\in\mathscr{G}$? Yes, because $\mathscr{C}$ is countable, so its union **is** the union of countably many members of $\mathscr{C}$.
2. Let $\mathscr{A}\subseteq\mathscr{G}$ be countable. Let $A\in\mathscr{A}$; by definition $A$ is the union of some countable family $\mathscr{C}_A\subseteq\mathscr{C}$. Let $C\in\mathscr{C}$; if $C\in\mathscr{C}_A$, then $C\subseteq\bigcup\mathscr{C}_A=A$. Now suppose that $C\notin\mathscr{C}_A$; $\mathscr{C}$ is a partition of $E$, so its members are pairwise disjoint, and therefore $C\cap D=\varnothing$ for each $D\in\mathscr{C}_A$. Thus, $C\cap A=C\cap\bigcup\mathscr{C}_A=\varnothing$. In other words, each $C\in\mathscr{C}$ is either a subset of $A$ or disjoint from $A$. Let $\mathscr{C}_{\mathscr{A}}=\bigcup_{A\in\mathscr{A}}\mathscr{C}_A$; $\mathscr{C}_{\mathscr{A}}$ is a countable subset of of $\mathscr{C}$, so $\bigcup\mathscr{C}_{\mathscr{A}}\in\mathscr{G}$. Show that $\bigcup\mathscr{A}=\bigcup\mathscr{C}_{\mathscr{A}}$, and conclude that $\bigcup\mathscr{A}\in\mathscr{G}$.
3. Let $A\in\mathscr{G}$. Then by definition there is a countable $\mathscr{C}_A\subseteq\mathscr{C}$ such that $A=\bigcup\mathscr{C}_A$. Let $\mathscr{D}=\mathscr{C}\setminus\mathscr{C}_A$; $\mathscr{D}$ is also a countable subset of $\mathscr{C}$, so if $D=\bigcup\mathscr{D}$, then $D\in\mathscr{G}$. Use the fact that $\mathscr{C}$ is a partition of $E$ to show that $D=E\setminus A$ and hence that $E\setminus A\in\mathscr{G}$.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks to show that if $C=\{C_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a partition of $E$, then the set $$G=\left\{\bigcup_{i\in I}C_i\mathrel{}\middle|\mathrel{} I\subseteq\Bbb N\right\}$$is closed under countable unions and complements.

Comment: Ok, how do you show that G is closed? Moreover, I need to show that G is infact the smallest sigma-algebra of C.

Comment: Just read the definition of $G$. The unions part is trivial, and the complement part follows from the fact that $C$ is a partition.

Comment: Ok thanks. Let me see if I understood this by giving a simple example:
Let C={A,B,C}, so then G={A,B,C,{A,B},{A,C},{B,C},{A,B,C}}
Shouldn't the empty set and E also be in G for it to be a sigma-algebra?

Comment: Your $G$ is all wrong. You didn't include the unions,  instead you just included the subsets of the partition. And not all of them either.